# Is possible to run shiny app from another shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

is it possible something like this:

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {

    output$text1 <- renderText({ 

      rep <- "Other"

      if (input$var == "First"){
                                                  rep <- "Run"}
      paste("You have selected", rep)

      runExample("01_hello")


    })

  }
)
```

Comment: Not sure, but have you seen [`shiny modules`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)? There's also an [upcoming webinar](https://pages.rstudio.net/Webinar-Apr6_Registration.html) on the topic.

Comment: interesting for what your need it? why not simply have app runned on other port ?

Comment: I have a few ready shiny applications. I want to make a menu with running them from one application.

Comment: JasonAizkalns, thank you, I'll take a look shiny modules